# How to deploy to Heroku with a different Gemfile / BUNDLE_GEMFILE

Tags: git, heroku, configuration, bundler, gemfile

I have an application that is tested on travis ci with 4 different themes which are configured using different Gemfiles via the BUNDLE_GEMFILE environment variable/ gemfile: option on travis. (https://github.com/learnery/learnery). 
I've also set up automatic deployment to heroku from travis ci. Now I want to deploy all 4 different configurations based on the different Gemfiles, but apparently setting BUNDLE_GEMFILE with

```
heroku config:set BUNDLE_GEMFILE=gemfiles/Gemfile.railsgirls
```

doesn't work - it results in this error in the heroku log:

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

- which I assume is due to the different Gemfile.lock present in the repository and the one produced by bundler.

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: Note: I'm considering a workaround modifying the git repository just for the deployment.

Comment: FWIW, I also tried using the absolute path to the alternate gemfile and got the same issue.  I've opened a ticket with them—we'll see if they have any ideas.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I have a similar problem. Thanks!